# Tabela com auto relacionamento

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, spring-mvc

Bom dia.

Tenho uma tabela que usa auto-relacionamento, acontece que nem todos os nomes inseridos possuem pai, mas não consigo criar um nome com pai null, há não ser o primeiro que foi criado, como no exemplo abaixo.

Exemplo:

```
id                                         name               pai

02016356-ED97-439B-8E78-4200547BD5AC      Presidente          null
239A0DB8-4282-45E5-B5AE-5A2702576E49      Diretoria Geral    02016356-ED97-439B-8E78-4200547BD5AC
```

Código do formulário

```
<form:select path="parent.id">
    <form:options items="${parents}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
</form:select>
```

Comment: A coluna `pai` está setada como valor padrão `NULL`?

Comment: Acho que minha falha está na hora de cadastrar, pq eu tenho um campo input aonde eu vou colocar o name e logo abaixo tenho uma combo para escolher o pai, porém, como esse valor está vindo do banco ele não tem um campo em branco para cadastrar null o pai, então a option já vem com um valor inicial.

Comment: A sua coluna está `UNIQUE`? Precisa disto?

Comment: A coluna não é unique.

Comment: E porque só aceita **um** `NULL`? Se não exige unicidade, deveria aceitar quantos você quiser.

Comment: ele aceita outros valores que não aceite null, mas é isso que eu quero, que aceite null, não consigo colocar via sistema, apenas diretamente no banco ...

Comment: Então talvez o problema esteja na aplicação, porque se não tem a restrição de `UNIQUE` tem que aceitar, e de fato você diz que aceita vários `NULL`. O problema não parece estar no banco de dados. Ou você explica melhor, ou muda a pergunta para focar na aplicação ou não sei como ajudar.

Comment: Você pode colocar o DDL (definição de criação da tabela) no corpo da sua pergunta?

Comment: Poste o código da montagem do select para selecionar o pai. Acho que o problema é na view e não no banco. O que você quer é permitir cadastrar sem pai, é isso?

Comment: Lucas, isso mesmo, o problema está na view.               <form:select path="parent.id">
     <form:options items="${parents}"  itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
    </form:select>

Comment: Que linguagem vc está usando?

Comment: Java com Spring MVC.